# How do I GROUP BY the next even date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sample table:

```
name   |   birthday
mike   |   1/1/2021
joe    |   1/2/2021
bob    |   1/3/2021
```

What I want to do is convert the birthday to the next even day then group by it.

Attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), even_birthday FROM table GROUP BY even_birthday
```

expected results:

```
count(*)  | even_birthday
2         | 1/2/2021
1         | 1/4/2021
```

using dates in the question in the m/d/yyyy format. I do not know how to come up with "even_birthday" so I can group by it.

Comment: "...using dates in the question in the m/d/yyyy format" -- please use the standard `DATE` type, not `VARCHAR`.

Comment: What would a date like `2020-03-31` "round" to? `2020-04-02`? Honestly, it seems like a calendar table might be a worth while investment for this odd logic.

Comment: @Larnu yes round up to 4/2/2020

Answer (score 4):

**Updated to allow for Larnu's impressive insight.**

The Modulus for odd days will be 1 while even would be 0.  So we simply apply the function `dateadd()`

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([name] varchar(50),[birthday] date)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('mike','1/1/2021')
,('joe','1/2/2021')
,('bob','3/31/2021')  -- Updated to illusrate Larnu's month end observation
 
Select cnt = count(*)
      ,even_birthdate 
 from @YourTable
 Cross Apply ( values ( dateadd(DAY,day(birthday) %2 ,birthday) ) )B(tDate)
 Cross Apply ( values ( dateadd(DAY,day(tDate)    %2 ,tDate   ) ) )C(even_birthdate)
 Group By even_birthdate
```

**Results**

```
cnt even_birthdate
2   2021-01-02
1   2021-04-02
```

Comment: Try the example date I give in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67709505/how-do-i-group-by-the-next-even-date?noredirect=1#comment119680332_67709505). It'll return `2021-04-01` for `2021-03-31`

Answer (score 3):

I wish John had kept his answer up, it was just missing a term. The trick is to add an extra day if the date is also the end of the month (and not an even date already like 4/30). Since SQL Server has the `EOMONTH()` function, this isn't terribly hard:

```sql
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE ([name] VARCHAR(50), [birthday] DATE)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES 
     ('mike','1/1/2021')
    ,('joe','3/31/2021')
    ,('bob','4/30/2021')
 
SELECT cnt = COUNT(*)
        ,even_birthdate = 
            CASE 
                WHEN DATEPART(DAY, birthday) % 2 = 0 THEN birthday
                ELSE DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(DAY,birthday) %2) + IIF(birthday = EOMONTH(birthday), 1, 0) ,birthday)
            END
 FROM @YourTable
 GROUP BY CASE 
              WHEN DATEPART(DAY, birthday) % 2 = 0 THEN birthday
              ELSE DATEADD(DAY,(DATEPART(DAY,birthday) %2) + IIF(birthday = EOMONTH(birthday), 1, 0) ,birthday)
          END
```

Comment: Larnu had an impressive catch.  Rather than the case, I used a cross appy and applied the logic on the results of tDate.   Either way +1